# The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full but it should have grown

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 that started showing that the TempDB transaction log was full. I checked the log file settings and there was no growth restriction and there was plenty of disk space.

I had no luck on finding an explanation of what could have caused this.

Has anyone experienced this in the past?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this occur when the file growth setting is set too high, so the growth event takes too long. Obviously this depends on your storage environment and performance details.

In my case, the 10% default growth rate was fine when the database was small, but at some point when the database got huge enough that the growth event took over 30 seconds, which was long enough that the original query timed out and rolled back. The rollback then cancelled the growth event, until the application re-tried the same query, and we got an endless loop.

So check your growth rates, or just pre-size your tempdb to a larger size.

Comment: And never use percentage growth

Comment: @Nic That too, although that requires micro-managing the growth rates as the database gets larger. You don't want a 1GB growth rate on a 10MB database, after all. I try to leave it as a % for very tiny databases, and a fixed amount for medium-to-large. In the case of this question, of course, TempDB should definitely be a fixed rate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The tempdb transaction log is set to 250 MB, Unlimited. Maybe it is too small

Comment: Growing to 250 mb should not (typically) time out.

Comment: @JoseChama I obviously don't know anything about the other databases and activity on your server to know whether a 250MB tempdb log is big enough, but yeah, try manually growing it to a larger size. But that doesn't answer the other part of my question, how is it set to grow? By a fixed amount? Or by a percent?

Comment: @BradC It is set to grow to a fixed amount of 250 MB and unlimited. The transaction log file initial size is 3 GB and there are 20 GB of free space in the tempdb log dedicated drive.

Comment: Ah, so it is growing *by* 250MB at a time? Yeah, unless it is on crazy slow disk (floppy drive? USB 1.0 thumbdrive?) a growth timeout doesn't seem like the most likely case here.

Comment: See if you can manually grow the tempdb 250 mb

Comment: Yes, it can grow 250 MB instantly. I am thinking that there might be some sort of blocking when it grows too fast.